# whenever hadoop (start-all.sh) namenode in safemode

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop, hadoop2

I'm study hadoop.. now.

whenever hadoop (`start-all.sh`) namenode in safemode...

`stop-all.sh` and start again it always in safemode...

```
hadoop version : 1.2.1
hadoop mode : pseudo distributed mode 
os : virtualbox ubuntu
```

after `hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave` it's working...

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/download/source/chapter4/WordCount$ hadoop fs -rmr /output2
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

rmr: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot delete /output2. Name node is in safe mode.
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/download/source/chapter4/WordCount$ hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

Safe mode is OFF
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/download/source/chapter4/WordCount$ hadoop fs -rmr /output2
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

Deleted hdfs://localhost:9000/output2
```

Comment: You should check why it is entering `safemode`! The Namenode's WebUI would give the details.

Comment: Can you let us know  the "dfs.safemode.threshold.pct" value from the hdfs-site.xml ?

Comment: i didn't write anything about dfs.safemode.threshold.pct
<name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
just have this

Comment: Thx You for helping me 
add property that name and value 0 in hdfs-site.xml
not appear safe mode message

Comment: You should fix the issue that is causing the NN to enter safemode. Setting it to **`0`** is not a solution unless you know what you are doing.